# Difference between returning a File vs FileStream from AWS to iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an MVC controller which returns a PDF document as a File. This file is downloaded into an iOS Newsstand app.

```
public ActionResult GetPdf(string id)
{
//Local
//string fileName = Server.MapPath("/NewsstandPDFs/" + id + ".pdf");
//FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName);
//return File(info.OpenRead(), "application/pdf");

//WORKING FROM S3
System.IO.MemoryStream data = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.Stream str = StorageFacade.getstream("NewsStandPdfs/" + id.ToUpper() + ".pdf", StorageScope.BigImages, null);
str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  //This rewinds the stream.
return new FileStreamResult(str, "application/pdf");
```

}

The Local file version works perfect and in IOS, I can use a progress bar to show the progress of the download.

However, if I use the AWS S3 one (which is the preference as I am looking to deliver the content from here (or cloudfront eventually), there is a significant delay before I can see the progress bar working in iOS. I'm guessing this is due to me having to stream the file from AWS before returning it, but I have been unable to come up with anything better.

Is there a way I can gradually send the stream, as it is received?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

If you want this content to be served from S3/Cloudfront then why are you getting it into your asp.net app and then sending it to the client?
An alternative way to do this is to prepare the link in the asp.net app and then let the (iOS) client fetch it directly from S3/CF.

Comment: Because I need .NET to handle the protection on the file (Using Membership facility). I understand you can do some levels of protection from within S3 etc but I dont want to have to manage this in 2 areas.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Do all authentication/authorization logic in asp.net - once you are happy then create a pre-signed temporary link to s3 which should expire in a few minutes and redirect / open a new window with that special url. See : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth

Comment: OK this works and makes a lot of sense as it doesnt lock up iOS. The only issue I have now is that as the file hasnt been downloaded, it seems impossible to show a progress bar on my interface as I dont know the size of it (in bytes). Any ideas?